# How to efficiently match two pandas data frame with regard to multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cosine-similarity

I have a dataframe df1 with 8M rows and 7 columns. One of the columns (‘ID’) is a sample ID, column A is a binary variable and other 5 columns are float values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((df_1_size, 5)), columns=list('BCDEF'))
df1['A'] = np.random.randint(1,3,size=df_1_size)
df1['ID'] = random.sample(range(0, df_1_size), df_1_size)
```

And df2 with 300K and same columns:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((df_2_size, 5)), columns=list('BCDEF'))
df2['A'] = np.random.randint(1,3,size=df_2_size)
df2['ID'] = random.sample(range(0, df_2_size), df_2_size)
```

I need to match the two data frames and find 300K*k samples from df1 which are similar to the samples in df2 with regard to columns A, B, C and D, without replacement.

I wrote a code where for each sample in df1 such as s_i, I first filter df2 based on the binary column, column A, and then find the cosine similarities between s_i and all samples in df2 for columns B, C and D using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` and then sort the distances and pick the closest (or top-k closest) and mark the selected sample in df2 as used. However, this algorithm takes 300K * 8M t to finish and practically speaking it has been running for two day and still not finished. Here is my (not so efficient) script:

```
df_1_size = 8000000
df_2_size = 300000
topk=1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((df_1_size, 5)), columns=list('BCDEF'))
df1['A'] = np.random.randint(1,3,size=df_1_size)
df1['ID'] = random.sample(range(0, df_1_size), df_1_size)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((df_2_size, 5)), columns=list('BCDEF'))
df2['A'] = np.random.randint(1,3,size=df_2_size)
df2['ID'] = random.sample(range(0, df_2_size), df_2_size)

match_based_on = ['B', 'C', 'D']

df1['MATCHED'] = 0
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    df1_filtered = df1[(df1['A'] == row['A']) & (df1['MATCHED'] == 0)]
    if len(df1_filtered) == 0:
        similarities = cdist(np.reshape(row[match_based_on].values, (1,len(match_based_on))), np.reshape(df1[df1['MATCHED'] == 0][match_based_on].values, (-1,len(match_based_on))), metric='cosine')
        matched_samples = df1[df1['MATCHED'] == 0].iloc[similarities[0].argsort()[:topk]]
        df1.loc[df1['ID'].isin(matched_samples['ID'].values),'MATCHED'] = 1
    else:
        similarities = cdist(np.reshape(row[match_based_on].values, (1,len(match_based_on))), np.reshape(df1_filtered[match_based_on].values, (-1,len(match_based_on))), metric='cosine')
        matched_samples = df1_filtered.iloc[similarities[0].argsort()[:topk]]
        df1.loc[df1['ID'].isin(matched_samples['ID'].values),'MATCHED'] = 1
pdb.set_trace()
df1[df1['MATCHED']==1].loc[:, df1.columns != 'MATCHED'].to_csv(df1_path[:-4]+'_matched.csv', index=False)
return 0
```

Any modification to the above solution or other different totally different solutions is very much appreciated.

PS. You can ignore matching based on column A if that helps making it easier to solve.

Comment: Just to clarify, would you like to find the columns in df1 that are exactly identical to df2, or columns that are similar?

Comment: The ideal is exactly identical, but that doesn’t always happen. So I just used cosine similarly and find the topk similar samples.

Comment: in your real case, the column A has limited number of different values (like 2 here)

Comment: column A is gender and in the data I work with it’s a binary value.  But at this point a solution that only works for columns B, C and D is good enough. I can ignore A if that makes is easier and more efficient to implement

Comment: I think given the large data you're working with, a pairwise comparison will regardless be consuming. Have you looked into writing a function instead and incorporating numba? That should speed it up considerably.

Comment: I've never used numba. This code is actually a function and part of a bigger code I have. So I simply write @numba.jit before the definition of my function and that's it? Do you know how much faster it will make it? Thanks

Comment: In line ```df1_filtered = df1[(df1['A'] == row['A']) & (df1['MATCHED'] == 0)]```, I believe you're only filtering the ```'A'``` column in ```df1``` based on the last sample's value of ```'A'``` from ```df2```, is that right?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi Yes, since A is a binary variable I am first filtering based on A to make sure both the sample in df1 and df2 has the same value for A. However, you can ignore matching based on A if this makes it easier and more efficient to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the full solution to your problem but it works for `topk = 1` 10x faster than the original one.

```
for a_val in df1['A'].unique():
    np1 = df1[df1['A'] == a_val][match_based_on].values
    np2 = df2[df2['A'] == a_val][match_based_on].values
    similarities = cdist(np2, np1, metric='cosine')
    df1_idx = np.argpartition(similarities, kth=topk, axis=1)[:,:topk]
    
    ind = df1[df1['A'] == a_val].iloc[df1_idx.flatten()].index
    df1.loc[ind, 'MATCHED_ID'] = df2[df2['A'] == a_val].ID.values
    df1.loc[df1['MATCHED_ID'] != "", 'MATCHED'] = 1
df1[df1['MATCHED_ID'] != ""].head()
```

Two main ideas:

- We shouldn't iterate over rows in DataFrames. All the methods usually support n-dimensional arrays, for example, `cdist`, `argsort`.
- Use `argpartition` instead of `argsort` if you need top k largest/smallest out of N values. `argsort` sorts all the values for  O(Nlog(N)), `argpartition` only choses a split between largest k and smallest N - k for O(N). If you need a sorted list of k items, sort argpartitioned (idx, value) pairs by value for O(klog(k)).